# Loading A Stable Diffusion/Dreambooth Model Without Retraining On Google Collab

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I'm using the following [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ShivamShrirao/diffusers/blob/main/examples/dreambooth/DreamBooth_Stable_Diffusion.ipynb?authuser=2#scrollTo=5V8wgU0HN-Kq) to train a Stable Diffusion (Dreambooth?) model. After a period of inactivity, the Google Colab notebook disconnects. Is there a way to resurrect the session from the saved model checkpoint file saved in my Google Drive without retraining the model? I hope this is clear. The video tutorial I used to work through this process is "[Inject Yourself Into the AI...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCcXrmVk1F0)"